# React - change another component

Tags: reactjs, state

I have `2 components`, what i want to do is:

When i **click a button in list item**, i want **another component to be visible**, and when i **type in a input text which is in "another component"**, i want to change a `<p>` in real time which is in Component List Item, I've tried so many different ways, how can i do that?

[image]

Comment: There are any number of ways this could be done--without details it's impossible to help. If the dependent component isn't a child then you either need to move state up (one or more levels) or use a state management solution (e.g., Redux).

Answer (score 1):

With props and controlled form elements.

I assume your two components are part of a parent component. Let this parent component hold the relevant states for these two sub-components and propagate the required information from there.

Or if you wanna go one step further, as mentioned in the comment, you can use Redux.

For more details, you need to provide code.